# Round to 2 decimal places on range AndroidPlot

Tags: androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot to create a simple XYPlot.
My y axis is (by default) rounding up to 1 decimal place. How can I change this to 2 decimal places?

I have found another answer that shows how you would do something similar with the old version of AndroidPlot: (this gets rid of decimal places but I assume this is the same function I would use)

```
// Gets rid of decimal places
mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
```

Does anyone know how to do this with AndroidPlot 1.*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since support was added in 1.x to display labels along any of the four edges of the graph, the way to attach a formatter was modified to support an arbitrary edge.

If you're using the standard domain value labels along the bottom of the plot, this should give you the same behavior as before:

```
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM)
    .setFormat(new DecimalFormat("0.0"));
```